# Not able to install VLC

Tags: release-freya, vlc

I am new in linux environment. And after doing some research, I found elementary is the best user friendly OS we have. I installed the 32-bit version of it, and now I am trying to install VLC using `sudo apt-get install vlc`. I am unable to install it and receive the below error.

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 vlc : Depends: vlc-nox (= 3.0.0~~git20150319+r59816+33~ubuntu14.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: libavcodec55 (>= 6:9.1-1) but it is not installable or
                libavcodec-extra-55 (>= 6:10~~git20131218.b3189af~ubuntu14.04.1) but it is not installable
       Depends: libavutil53 (>= 6:9.1-1) but it is not installable
       Depends: libfreerdp1 (>= 1.0.1) but it is not installable
       Depends: libqtgui4 (>= 4:4.8.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: libsdl-image1.2 (>= 1.2.10) but it is not installable
       Depends: libvlccore8 but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: libvncclient0 (>= 0.9.9) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: libxcb-composite0 but it is not installable
       Depends: libxcb-keysyms1 (>= 0.3.9) but it is not installable
       Depends: libxcb-randr0 (>= 1.1) but it is not installable
       Depends: libxcb-xv0 (>= 1.2) but it is not installable
       Recommends: vlc-plugin-notify (= 3.0.0~~git20150319+r59816+33~ubuntu14.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
       Recommends: vlc-plugin-samba (= 3.0.0~~git20150319+r59816+33~ubuntu14.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I tried searching in net, I tried executing sudo apt-get update/upgrade. added vlc repository. But still I am getting this error.

Please let me know how can I fix this.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have Ubuntu restricted extras installed?

Comment: No, i tried installing but i got the below error.

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ubuntu-restricted-extras : Depends: ubuntu-restricted-addons but it is not installable
                            Recommends: ttf-mscorefonts-installer but it is not installable
                            Recommends: unrar but it is not going to be installed
                            Recommends: gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad-multiverse but it is not installable
                            Recommends: libavcodec-extra but it is not going to be installed

Comment: @Ajay , Could you add output of `grep "^[ ]*deb " -r /etc/apt/sources.list* ; echo q | aptitude -s install  vlc ; apt-get -s -o Debug::pkgProblemResolver=yes install vlc` , you may upload it to http://paste.ubuntu.com

Answer (score 2):

Try removing vlc with:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge vlc*
```

after that you will need to remove ppa that you have added:
Install ppa-purge:

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
```

You need to know what ppa you have added I pressume it's ppa:videolan/stable-daily but you need to check the exact ppa in the bash history:

```
cd
scratch-text-editor .bash_history
```

When you find ppa use following commands (if you added different ppa just replace  ppa:videolan/stable-daily  with your ppa).

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:videolan/stable-daily  
sudo apt-get update
```

Reinstall VLC:

```
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

This should help, if not read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26957117/unmet-dependency-when-installing-vlc-on-ubuntu-14-04)